# How to auto refresh a division with some PHP content within it

Tags: javascript, php, html

I googled abit and found a script, to reload a division.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  setInterval("$('#downshow').load('message.php');", 5000);
</script>
```

here downshow is my division where contents need to be refreshed. its like chat app, and messages between me and my friend needs to continoulsy reload.

My division downshow is something like below...

```
$getmessages= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pvt_messages WHERE (user_from='$active_username' && user_to='$username') || (user_from='$username' && user_to='$active_username')  ORDER BY id ASC ") or die(mysql_error());

                        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($getmessages )) 
                        {
                            $body = $row['msg_body'];   
                            $date_send = $row['date'];
                            $opened = $row['opened'];
                            $whosent= $row['user_from'];
                            $whoreceived= $row['user_to'];
                            $seen=$row['opened'];

                            /////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                            $get_user_info = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE (username='$whosent')");
                            ////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                            $get_info = mysql_fetch_assoc($get_user_info);
                            $profilepic_info = $get_info['profile_pic'];
                            if ($profilepic_info == "") {
                             $profilepic_info = "./images/default_pic.jpg";
                            }
                            else
                            {
                             $profilepic_info = "./userdata/profile_pics/".$profilepic_info;
                            }
                            echo "
                                    <div style='float: left;padding-top:5px; padding-left:20px;'>
                                            <img src='$profilepic_info' height='50' width='40'>
                                    </div>
                                    <div style='margin-left:50px;padding-top:5px;'>
                                        <a href='$whosent' style='color:black'> $whosent</a> $body
                                    </div></br>
                                    <div  style=' margin-left:30px;'>
                                    <font size='2px'>sent on: $date_send</font>
                                     <br />
                                    </div>
                                    <hr />
                            ";



                        }
```

I would have kept the content of this division in some other page i.e. message.php and then include it just as

```
    <div id='downshow'  style='bottom:0px;'class='see_message'>
<?php include("message.php"); ?>
</div>
```

But if i do this, there will be lots of problem like, session_start() issues, variable $active_username ll be obtained easily by $active_username=$_SESSION['username'] bt couldnt obtain varibale $username in message.php.

so instead of including the division content as "message.php". i want that code to be in main php file itself.

so want to as instead of

```
setInterval("$('#downshow').load('message.php');", 5000);
```

how can i use

```
setInterval("$('#downshow').load('????????????');", 5000);
```

load the division itself?????????????

Thankyou in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

```
setInterval(function(){ $('#downshow').load('message.php');

}, 5000);
```

Comment: yes, i tried that. and it works fine only if some constant data was to be retrived. but my page is for chat, so if I only load .load('message.php'). than in message.php, there will be no active session, no $active_username i.e. me and $username i.e. my certain friend whose conversation with me, i am tryin to load in the division

Comment: I even tried setInterval(function(){ $('#downshow').load('message.php?u=$username');

}, 5000); Here $username is the friend whose conversation , i m trying to load.. but its not working

Comment: Try this-> `(function(){ $('#downshow').load('message.php?u=<?php echo $username;?>'); }, 5000);`

Answer (score 1):

This is not the best way to do this

You should look at [AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) and create a template for the HTML.

This way you can send information to the server (such as requesting items since a particular time, or from a particular 'room') and only send back the important data (send it back as [JSON](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/)) and populate your template.

This will reduce traffic and load on your server and will reduce latency in your application as you are only sending back the important data - not the HTML to go with it!

Additionally use [classes](http://www.htmldog.com/guides/css/intermediate/classid/) for each of the items instead of inline styles as it will make your code easier to maintain.

Comment: Thankyou, I appriciate that. But these inline styling is so i would first complete styling fast, and later m planing to use class :)

Comment: No problem - wasn't sure! definately go this route - it will be far more learning BUT you will use AJAX a LOT during coding if you want nice fluid designs and a mini chat application is a great way to learn it! Good Luck and if you find my answer helpful a +1 is always appreciated (and an accept if you don't find a better answer!)